# Website Directory accessed through google

Tags: web, directory

So, the directory is hidden and whenever its accessed.

> **403 - Forbidden**: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

But, for example, if you search google for a specific file in it, it will still show up.  So, can someone be able to access the whole directory through google using a similar method or other?

For example, there is a file called `1.txt` and `2.txt`.  If I search google for `1.txt`, it shows up with the address to the its location in the directory, so if someone was to change the address to just end with `2.txt`, instead of `1`, then he has access to this file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which webserver and operating system we're talking about, I just write down the situation for Linux (Debian) and apache2.

Assuming you have a directory PHP whose access rights are `0000` - meaning none, the webserver's user (`www-data`) can't access the folder and therefore answers with a Forbidden message.

However, if you have a `test.txt` within the folder and whose rights are `0000` you still cannot access it, because apache2 cannot read the `.htaccess` file (since it doesn't have permission to) and denied the access to be safe.

The same applies if you have the `chmod` of `test.txt` and `.htaccess` on `777` (rwx for everyone).

This is highly depended on the webserver and operating system - but basically, it's down to access rights. For apache2, you could on top define a htaccess file with `Deny from all`.